# How to resolve "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found"

Tags: android, google-play

I have used the in-app purchase functionality in our android application. When I click on my Product item and click 'buy' button I open the android market, but it shows a pop up saying "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found". How to solve this problem. Please suggest.

Comment: this link is also helpful https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/A2RM4P34zo0

Answer (score 3):

Have you created the product list on the publisher console for the application in question correctly?
And even if you have created and saved the product list for in-app billing, you have to publish them (the application itself need not be published and can remain as a draft ver) to make it visible to the outside world.
Last but not least, you have to test in-app billing implementation from a device where the test email account is the primary account on the device used for testing. You cannot use a device where the primary account is the same as the android market publisher account.

In future, provide more details on why you might be facing as issue. You can say what all you have tried to solve the issue and that gives us a pretty good idea what else can be tried to help you see the light at the end of the tunnel. The way you have posted the question, we are not sure at what point in the tunnel you are at :)

HTH.

Comment: Ugh.. I just spent over half an hour trying to figure this out and can't believe I didn't think of actually publishing the In-App Product itself.  That did it for me.  Thanks for the obvious tip.