# "the item you were attempting to purchase could not be found" after following instructions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

So I am following the instructions at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html for testing my app for in-app billing. I have also already read

- [In app Purchase issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182272/in-app-purchase-issue-in-android)
- [How to resolve “The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743429/how-to-resolve-the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found)
- [How to resolve "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213227/how-to-resolve-the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found)

My products are activated, I am using a testing account that is not registered under my name; my apk is in draft mode; my sku match the product ids. I am still getting the infamous `the item you were attempting to purchase could not be found`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I misspelled the SKU I was trying to test.

Comment: I am having the same problem! I'm rather ashamed to admit it, but I don't know what to send as the SKU string. Should I be sending "sku_name", or "com.mycompany.myproduct.sku_name", or something else? I've tried both of those solutions, with and without capitalization, and nothing seems to work! What did your SKU string look like?

Comment: SKU can be any of those format as long as Google play form accepts. I normally used just the name as "unlock" "fullapp" and it works perfect.