# Resolve the "item you were attempting could not be found" error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have include the inappBilling  sample into my project  provided by Google and uploaded signed apk in play store and not add any product in **In-app Product**  section when i test my app with test account it shows this error **item you were attempting could not be found** when i click on Gas button or other button.

My question is

1. Is it necessary to add product in In-app Product section. can we not test with reserved product id in my project.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you must publish a product to be able to test In App Billing.

good answers to the workflow are at:

[How to resolve "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213227/how-to-resolve-the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found)